# Are stone bricks stronger than smooth stone?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Aside from the aesthetics, do stone bricks have any benefit over smooth stone? Will creepers cause less structural damage to my luxurious stately-home if I build it (walls and floor) out of stone bricks?

It's probably the floor I'm most concerned about. One-brick thick walls will probably sustain damage regardless of the stone type, but if I have, say, two-brick thick floors of stone-brick for my house and grounds rather than smooth-stone will that be more resilient to creeper damage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Minecraft Wiki:

- [Stone Bricks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Stone_Bricks) have 30 Blast Resistance.
- [Smooth Stones](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Smooth_stone) also have 30 Blast Resistance.

Actually, most construction blocks out of stone and harder materials have 30 blast resistance as stated [Here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Explosion#Blast_resistance)

Comment: Wow, so according to that link, a block of diamond has the same blast resistance as a block of stone? That seems unusual. Guess there's no point building my palace out of diamond then! (Well, not from a structural-integrity point of view anyway.)

Comment: @JonW Pretty much. Afaik, all you gotta do is to wall it off with cacti or make a moat, and that should solve most of your issues... or you do like me and build into a mountain Dwarf Fortress style!

Comment: You might as well keep cats around your base and spawn proof the inside.